# Cardinality of a symmetric difference under specific conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ be sets such that any intersection involving more than two of them is empty. We denote with $\Delta$ the symmetric difference operator. Then:
\begin{equation*}
 \lvert \Delta_{i=1}^n A_i\rvert = \Bigl\lvert\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\Bigr\rvert - \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n \lvert A_i \cap A_j\rvert
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of inclusion exclusion. It can be proven by induction on $n.$ For $n=2$ it is obvious.

Assuming it holds for $n,$ note that
$$\triangle_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i = B \triangle A_{n+1}$$
for $B = \triangle_{i=1}^n A_i.$ Hence, it has cardinality
$$|\triangle_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i| = |B \cup A_{n+1}| - |B \cap A_{n+1}|.$$

How many elements are in the union? Well, $|B| + |A_{n+1}| - |B\cap A_{n+1}|$ elements. So now we just compute that intersection.

If $x \in B \cap A_{n+1},$ then $x \in B$ and $x\in A_{n+1}.$ For $x \in B$ to happen, we need $x$ to belong to exactly one of the sets $A_1, ..., A_n$ (if it belonged to more than one, it would be excluded). Thus, $x \in B\cap A_{n+1}$ if and only if $x \in A_i \cap A_{n+1}$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n,$ and $x \not\in A_j$ for any other $j \neq n+1, i.$ Since triple intersections of sets are empty, though, we know that the $x\not\in A_j$ condition is automatic, so $x \in B\cap A_{n+1}$ if and only if $x \in A_i \cap A_{n+1}$ for some $i,$ and $i$ is unique, so that $B\cap A_{n+1}$ is the disjoint union of the sets $A_i\cap A_{n+1}$ as $1 \leq i \leq n$ varies.

So, the size is
$$|\triangle_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i | = |B| + |A_{n+1}| - 2|B\cap A_{n+1}| = |B| + |A_{n+1}| - 2\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i \cap A_{n+1}|.$$

Plugging in our formula for $|B|$ from the inductive step, we have
$$|\triangle_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i| = \left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right| + |A_{n+1}| - \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i\cap A_{n+1}| - \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} |A_i \cap A_j|.$$

So, the claim is equivalent to showing
$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i\right| = \left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right| + |A_{n+1}| - \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i\cap A_{n+1}|.$$

This can be inductively proven in a similar way, using that the triple intersections are empty and a simple counting argument.

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't even use induction for the last step, we just need to know that $\lvert A \cup B\rvert = \lvert A\rvert + \lvert B\rvert - \lvert A \cap B\rvert$, use one of the distributivity laws for union and intersection and the fact that the sets $A_i \cap A_{n+1}$ are mutually disjoint.